# fields_for and has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, fields-for

I have these models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_lines
  has_many :prizes, :through => :order_lines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_lines
end

class Prize < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_lines  
end

class OrderLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :prize
end
```

I would like a nested form in the order form that displays every prize with a text box next to it where the user can enter pieces (eg. the amount to order). When the form is submitted the create action should create the order_lines accordingly. I can't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the Order model use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :prizes`, instead of what you have.

After that it's easy, just add a form in the view (there's no additional step controller)

```
<%= form_for @order do |order_form| %>
  ..
  <%= order_form.fields_for :prizes do |prizes_form| %>
    <%= prizes_form.text_field :piece %>
    ..
  <% end %>
 ..
<% end %>
```

This is straight from the documentation... [You should definitely check that first](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When doing that, fields_for does not iterate through the prizes. The code in the block doesn't run at all.

Comment: The code runs normally, but it probably doesn't show anything because there the order doesn't have any prize. If you want to edit and instantiate a prize in the order form, you should add @order.prizes.build in the controller. Check out [this link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) for more information

Comment: If I do a @order.prizes.build all I get is one empty prize instance in the block. The link to RailsCasts only apply if I have a one-to-many association. That is not the case here :-(